# Asp:button and its controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, model-view-controller, webforms

I'm working on an webapp, following de Model-View-Controller pattern. The view is written in html, javascript and asp. The controller is written in c#.

I have a problem, because I'm trying to use an asp:Button but it doesn't connect with the controller as it does. In other Q&A I have read that if I use the property **UseSubmitBehaviour** it should work, and it works, but in that case the textboxes, the dropdownlist and the UploadFile elements seem empty.

This is the code I have in the view:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PaginaBase.master.cs" Inherits="webGestionPartes.PaginaBase" %>
<label>Tipo de petición</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="tipoPeticion" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>

<label>Título</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="tituloPeticion" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>

<label>Descripción</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="descripcionPeticion" runat="server" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="15"></asp:TextBox>

<label>Adjuntar documento</label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
<asp:Label ID="UploadStatusLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>

<asp:Button ID="bntEnviarPeticion" runat="server" Text="Enviar" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />
```

And this is what i have in the controller:

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                // Call a helper method routine to save the file.
                peUsuario.Enviar_Peticion_Adjunto(peSession.oPerfilSeleccionado.idOrganizacion, peSession.idEmpleado, tipoPeticion.Text, tituloPeticion.Text, descripcionPeticion.Text, FileUpload1.PostedFile);
            }
            else
            {
                peUsuario.Enviar_Peticion(peSession.oPerfilSeleccionado.idOrganizacion, peSession.idEmpleado, tipoPeticion.Text, tituloPeticion.Text, descripcionPeticion.Text);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            escribeLog.Error("", ex);
        }
    }
```

PS: there are things written in spanish, sorry if you don't understand. And sorry about my english too.

Comment: If you're going to follow the Model View Controller pattern, why not use the [ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.asp.net/mvc) or [ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) frameworks, which are much easier to follow the pattern with? And much more pleasant to work with.

Comment: The specifications of this app are given to me by the customer, I am not allowed to change them, sorry...

Comment: Is `UploadButton_Click` defined in `PaginaBase.master.cs`?

Comment: @getsetcode yes! the code below is from PaginaBase.master.cs

Comment: Are you setting `UseSubmitBehaviour` to true or false? It's true by default and only switches between default browser submit and Javascript-based submit. Shouldn't have any impact on the client side. Do you see the page post back when `UseSubmitBehaviour` is true? If so, are you setting the values of your textboxes, or binding dropdown list, on every postback? You should only do these if `!Page.IsPostBack`.

Comment: @getsetcode I've tried modifying the SubmitBehaviour, if it is set as true, the button does nothing, and if it's false, it works as it does when I wrote this question

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more code in that case. I can't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: The solution I have found is creating a modal and working there with the FileUpload. This modal is activated when I click an icon. IT WORKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have found is creating a modal and working there with the FileUpload. This modal is activated when I click an icon. IT WORKS!!!